# Scala group by with mapped keys

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a DataFrame that has a list of countries and the corresponding data. However the countries are either iso3 or iso2.

```
dfJSON
    .select("value.country")
    .filter(size($"value.country") > 0)
    .groupBy($"country")
    .agg(count("*").as("cnt"));
```

Now this country field can have USA as the country code or US as the country code. I need to map both USA / US ==> "United States" and then do a `groupBy`. How do I do this in scala.

Answer (score 0):

Create another DataFrame with `country_name`, `iso_2` & `iso_3` columns.
Join your actual DataFrame with this DataFrame & Apply your logic on that data.

Check below code for sample.

````
scala> countryDF.show(false)                                                                                                                                                            
+-------------------+-----+-----+                                                                                                                                                       
|country_name       |iso_2|iso_3|                                                                                                                                                       
+-------------------+-----+-----+                                                                                                                                                       
|Afghanistan        |AF   |AFG  |                                                                                                                                                       
|?land Islands      |AX   |ALA  |                                                                                                                                                       
|Albania            |AL   |ALB  |                                                                                                                                                       
|Algeria            |DZ   |DZA  |                                                                                                                                                       
|American Samoa     |AS   |ASM  |                                                                                                                                                       
|Andorra            |AD   |AND  |                                                                                                                                                       
|Angola             |AO   |AGO  |                                                                                                                                                       
|Anguilla           |AI   |AIA  |                                                                                                                                                       
|Antarctica         |AQ   |ATA  |                                                                                                                                                       
|Antigua and Barbuda|AG   |ATG  |                                                                                                                                                       
|Argentina          |AR   |ARG  |                                                                                                                                                       
|Armenia            |AM   |ARM  |                                                                                                                                                       
|Aruba              |AW   |ABW  |                                                                                                                                                       
|Australia          |AU   |AUS  |                                                                                                                                                       
|Austria            |AT   |AUT  |                                                                                                                                                       
|Azerbaijan         |AZ   |AZE  |                                                                                                                                                       
|Bahamas            |BS   |BHS  |                                                                                                                                                       
|Bahrain            |BH   |BHR  |                                                                                                                                                       
|Bangladesh         |BD   |BGD  |                                                                                                                                                       
|Barbados           |BB   |BRB  |                                                                                                                                                       
+-------------------+-----+-----+                                                                                                                                                       
only showing top 20 rows                                                                                                                                                                ```
````

```
scala> df.show(false)                                                                                                                                                                   
+-------+                                                                                                                                                                               
|country|                                                                                                                                                                               
+-------+                                                                                                                                                                               
|USA    |                                                                                                                                                                               
|US     |                                                                                                                                                                               
|IN     |                                                                                                                                                                               
|IND    |                                                                                                                                                                               
|ID     |                                                                                                                                                                               
|IDN    |                                                                                                                                                                               
|IQ     |                                                                                                                                                                               
|IRQ    |                                                                                                                                                                               
+-------+
```

```
scala> df
.join(countryDF,(df("country") === countryDF("iso_2") || df("country") === countryDF("iso_3")),"left")
.select(df("country"),countryDF("country_name"))
.show(false)             
+-------+------------------------+                                                                                                                                                      
|country|country_name            |                                                                                                                                                      
+-------+------------------------+                                                                                                                                                      
|USA    |United States of America|                                                                                                                                                      
|US     |United States of America|                                                                                                                                                      
|IN     |India                   |                                                                                                                                                      
|IND    |India                   |                                                                                                                                                      
|ID     |Indonesia               |                                                                                                                                                      
|IDN    |Indonesia               |                                                                                                                                                      
|IQ     |Iraq                    |                                                                                                                                                      
|IRQ    |Iraq                    |                                                                                                                                                      
+-------+------------------------+
```

```
scala> df
.join(countryDF,(df("country") === countryDF("iso_2") || df("country") === countryDF("iso_3")),"left")
.select(df("country"),countryDF("country_name"))
.groupBy($"country_name")
.agg(collect_list($"country").as("country_code"),count("*").as("country_count"))
.show(false)
+------------------------+------------+-------------+
|country_name            |country_code|country_count|
+------------------------+------------+-------------+
|Iraq                    |[IQ, IRQ]   |2            |
|India                   |[IN, IND]   |2            |
|United States of America|[USA, US]   |2            |
|Indonesia               |[ID, IDN]   |2            |
+------------------------+------------+-------------+
```